# Java - cannot reference "repaint" in "main"

Tags: java, swing, animation, static

I have been trying to animate a circle shape in java. However, when I call `repaint()` in my animation loop in the class main, I get an error that I cannot reference a non-static method inside a static one, and main has to be static. This is a simple program and it should work, but for some reason it doesn't. Also, according to [this](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game2.html) tutorial, I did everything all right.

My code:

```
    package com.ultraluminous.pong;

    import java.awt.Color;    
    import java.awt.Graphics;   
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;   
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;   

    import javax.swing.JFrame;  
    import javax.swing.JPanel;   

    public class Game extends JPanel{   
        static int x = 0;  
        static int y = 0;

        private static void shift(){
            x+=1;
            y+=1;
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                super.paint(g);
                Graphics2D Graph = (Graphics2D) g;
                Graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                Graph.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                Graph.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
                Graph.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
            }

            public static void main (String[] args){
                JFrame Win = new JFrame("Pong");
                    Win.add(new Game());
                    Win.setResizable(false);
                    Win.setSize(900, 600);
                    Win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    Win.setVisible(true);
                    while (true) {
                        shift();
                        repaint();
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }   
            }
      }
```

Comment: Throw the stack trace in here.

Comment: Strongly recommend to not start variable names with capital case. Standard convention is to start variable names with lowercase.

Comment: Win.repaint(); will work. Do something about Thread.sleep(10), since it could throw an InterruptedException.

Comment: Don't override paint(). Override paintComponent() instead.

Comment: @CostisAivalis Cheers man, please add your comment as an aswer so I can choose it. Kudos for the deit, too ;)!

Comment: @UltraLuminous: Next time! The Q has been marked a duplicate. :-)